# DataType mismatch although data types are same

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a strange thing happening in my below code.

I get data type of column Sales order Lineitems as well as SO field from form via VarType, both have string data type with number 8, but I still get datatype mismatch error.

```vb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from [Sales Order Lineitems] where [Sales Order Number]=" & CStr(Forms![Sales Order]!SO))
```

If I run code like this, no error happens

```vb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from [Sales Order Lineitems] where [Sales Order Number]='10007'")
```

How can I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Don't leave out the quotes:

```vb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from [Sales Order Lineitems] where [Sales Order Number]='" & CStr(Forms![Sales Order]!SO) & "'")
```